# jQuery not() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Why doesn't the fiddle work correctly

HTML

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="class-fake fake-class">Some other data</div>
        <div> Some data</div>
    </div>
    <span>
        Span data
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*").not(".class-fake").css("color", "red");
    //Div with class-fake should not turn to red
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSL9H/

I replaced $("*") with $("div") yet the results are the same.

EDIT :

What i'm trying to do:
Basically i want add an event to the body so that if any element other than those matched by `$('.class-fake')` is clicked a function is executed. So I'm using event delegation so that every element doesn't get an event attached to it:

```
$("*").on("click", ":not(.class-fake)", function(){
 //execute
});
```

Also, `.class-fake` elements have a separate `click` event added to them.

The above is also not working. The event is fired even if i click on `.class-fake` elements. So i though of using `$("*").not('.class-fake')` since `.not()` is recommended over `:not()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't set the style on the `div` with the class `class-fake`.

It sets the style on all the parents of the element, including the `html` and `body` elements, and that makes the text inside that `div` red also, as it inherits the color from the parent elements.

Some styles are inherited, like the `color` style. You can use a different style, like `border`, that isn't inherited to see that the style actually isn't set on the element:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSL9H/3/

---

#### Edit:

You can't keep events from happening by excluding them from a delegate, because the event will just bubble and happen to the parent element instead.

Catch the event on all elements, use `stopPropagation` to keep it from bubbling, and only execute your code if the element that was clicked on is not the one you want to exclude:

```
$("body").on("click", "*", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (!$(e.currentTarget).is('.class-fake')) {
    // execute
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rNqw8/1/

Comment: @VarunAchar: Added a way to handle that above.

Comment: @VarunAchar: Not very much. There is some overhead as it will check the class for every click, but there is only one event handler bound on the `body` element that does that.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `not()` is not excluding the parent `div` element. It's hard to guide you on a better method as you've not specifically said what you're trying to do.

A quick fix is simply the following, but this is very DOM structure dependant:

```
$("div > div > div").not(".class-fake").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: Div with class-fake should not turn to red

Comment: Basically i want add an event to the body so that if any element other than those matched by $('.class-fake') is clicked a function is executed.

Comment: Using event delegation so that all elements don't get an event attached to them

Answer (score 2):

As Rory McCrossan says, you're only saying that you don't want to apply that css rule to .class-fake, but you're applying it to its parent and so on, making .class_fake inherit that rule.

You can do this:

```
$(".class-fake").css("color", "black");
```

EDIT:

It seems like propagation to me. Use this http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$(".class-fake").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: and you click .class-fake and the event occurs?

Comment: There is a separate click event attached to .class-fake elements. Those events will also stop firing

Comment: Not it will not, only the propagation stops, this means that only the events attached to that selector (.class-fake) will be removed. From jQuery documentation: "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."

Answer (score 2):

Jquery will result this:

```
   <div style="color: red">
         <div style="color: red">
             <div class="class-fake fake-class">Some other data</div>
             <div style="color: red"> Some data</div>
          </div>
          <span style="color: red">
              Span data
           </span>
    </div>
```

As you can see... the parent has a "color: red"... so the child is red too...